# Reduction of rows in pd-Dataframe to single row by id in dask

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I have several large dataframes with ~5 columns, and ~1kk rows. The first column contains id values (sorted). Now I would like to reduce the amount of data by applying a function to each column separately over all rows with the same id, i.e. when starting from

```
    id  A   B
0   0   1   2
1   0   2   3
2   1   3   4
3   1   4   5
```

and applying `sum()`, I would like to get

```
    id  A_sum   B_sum
0   0   3   5
1   1   7   9
```

As my data is quite large, I thought of using dask for that, and split the dataframe into smaller partitions. For that, I created the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import dask
import numpy as np
import dask.dataframe as dadf

# General variables
number_of_diff_ids = 2
entry_len = 2
number_of_cols = 5
col_pattern = "col_"

# Generation of test db
target_df = pd.DataFrame()
for id_val in range(number_of_diff_ids):
    data_dict = {}
    data_dict["id"] = [id_val] * entry_len
    for col_val in range(number_of_cols):
        data_arr = [id_val * 10 + col_val] * entry_len
        data_dict[f"{col_pattern}{col_val}"] = data_arr
    if id_val == 0:
        target_df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
    else:
        target_df = pd.concat([target_df, pd.DataFrame(data_dict)], ignore_index=True)

# Split into partitions
dask_df = dadf.from_pandas(target_df, npartitions = len(set(target_df.id.values)))

# Function to apply to the dataframe
def test_func(d):
    empty_dict = {}
    for column in d.columns.values:
        print(f"Column: {column}, {d[column]}, sum: {np.sum(d[column].values)}\n\n")
        if "id" not in column:
            empty_dict[f"{column}_sum"] = np.sum(d[column].values)
            empty_dict[f"{column}_max"] = np.max(d[column].values)
        else:
            empty_dict[column] = d["id"].values[0]
    print(f"Prepared dict: {empty_dict}\n\n")
    pd_frame = pd.DataFrame(empty_dict, index=[0])
    #pd_frame.columns = list(empty_dict.keys())
    print(f"Return pd: {pd_frame}\n\n")
    return pd_frame#dask.dataframe.from_dict(pd_frame, npartitions=1)

# Application of function
compressed_dask_df = dask_df.map_partitions(lambda df: df.apply(test_func, axis=1), meta=(None, "f8"))
compressed_dask_df.compute()
```

The last step, however, fails with `AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'`. How can I solve this, and what exactly am I doing wrong here?

Moreover, is that approach efficient at all? And can it be ensured that by splitting it into `n` partitions, that every partition only contains a single id?

Comment: `df.groupby('id', as_index=False).sum()`